# Windows 7 Remote Desktop stops with copy paste action after copy and paste on local machine

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm working on a local PC with Windows 7 64-bit and I have a remote desktop connection to a PC with the same config.

When I paste a large file from my remote desktop PC to my local PC it works... until I start an other copy and paste action on my local machine. Why does the remote desktop connection stops copying when I do a local copy and paste action?

I can't believe I'm the only one with this, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Clipboard support in RDP sucks.  A similar about RDP clipboard issues was asked yesterday.  http://serverfault.com/questions/391595/distributed-clipboard-with-drag-and-drop-text-and-file-support

Comment: you can say that, I have to paste large files, so it takes a while. I hoped there would be a solution to fix it. maybe I have to use different software for this?

Comment: Would there be another option opposed to copying those files trough RDP? E.g. trough CIFS?

Comment: Do you know some options with a secure connection?

Comment: I am just having the same issue. The file copy from remote to local goes well until I do a mere copy/paste (e.g. in a text editor) on my local machine. Tried to reset the rdpclip.exe thing, with no luck - I think this "solves" another issue anyway (where remote copy/paste does not work at all).

Answer (score 0):

Working on Windows 8.1 and the new Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7 still has this same issue.

A workaround is not to use copy paste, but drag the files to the new location while copying files in your remote desktop. Maybe Windows 10 is the answer.